# How do I determine the distribution of my spatial data in order to choose a kernel density bandwidth estimation method?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro, kernel-density, bandwidth

I'm using kernel density estimates (KDE) to get animal home ranges. When researching bandwidth selection for KDE, I'm learning that it depends heavily on the data's distribution. I'd love to use ArcGIS Pro's default of Silverman's rule of thumb, but it assumes my data is normally distributed. I can't figure out how to determine if my spatial data is normally distributed or multimodal. I've researched how to do this in R, Python, and ArcGIS but I cannot find any step by step instruction.

Answer (score 0):

These type of statistical tools tend to be outside my skill set so I may have misunderstood your requirements (because I don't fully understand the tool). When you say my *data is normally distributed* are you referring to what would be set as the population field in the [Kernel Density tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/kernel-density.htm#ESRI_USAGES_BBA78DC9676A44A8A155C745BDDA30E5)? If so why don't you simply create a [histogram chart](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/analysis/geoprocessing/charts/histogram.htm) of it and you'll quick see if is normal or skewed. Just open the attribute table, right click on the population field and select Statistics.

If you are referring to the points locations may be you could use the [Average Nearest neighbour tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/average-nearest-neighbor.htm) that gives you an index of dispersion?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Hornbydd. I was referring to the point locations. I used the Average Nearest Neighbor tool and found that my data is clustered. I'm confused as to why ArcGIS Pro's default bandwidth estimation method would require normally distributed data and what to do when it's not normally distributed, but that's a question for another post.